# Why does my array populate only after I reenter the view?

Tags: arrays, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, populate

I'm trying to populate an `array` with data using this code:

```
tmp = [[[InternalContactsHandler sharedBuffer] contacts] sortedArrayUsingSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"nameOfContactCompare:")];
```

To check whether it has been populated, I set a `count` on it:

```
NSLog(@"my code: %lu", (unsigned long)tmp.count);
```

It returns 0 though. But if I enter another `view`, then go back to the original view, the `NSLog` shows a count of 49, indicating that it has been populated.

I thought it was an issue with `synchronization`, so I added a `block` which I assume is similar to `swifts` `completion-handler`. Like this:

```
- (void)myFunc:(void(^)(void))callback {
    tmp = [[[InternalContactsHandler sharedBuffer] contacts] sortedArrayUsingSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"nameOfContactCompare:")];
    callback();
}
```

And in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self myFunc:^ {
    NSLog(@"my code: %lu", (unsigned long)tmp.count);
}];
```

But still, the very same problem persists. I should mention that the code is used elsewhere in the project to great success, the array being instantly populated. Any thoughts?

***UPDATE***
I went into `tmp = [[[InternalContactsHandler sharedBuffer] contacts]` in debug mode in both old working code and new non-working code. They follow the exact same path, to here:

```
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    NSLog(@"GOES IN HERE");
    sharedContactsBuffer = [[InternalContactsHandler alloc] init];
});
return sharedContactsBuffer;
```

But with original use, `contacts` is instantly populated with 49 elements whereas it has 0 in new use of code:

[image]

Perhaps it has something to do with `dispatch_once(&pred, ^{...` Not sure what that means.

Comment: This doesn't have to do with synchronization. If `sortedArrayUsingSelector` ran asynchronously it would take a completion handler itself.

What is calling this code? Is it in a ViewController?

Comment: @atreat OK, thanks, good to know. Yes, it's in a VC. I have tried in both viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad, same result.

Comment: Is it possible there is a bug in InternalContactsHandler where it sometime doesn't return results? Maybe the first call it needs to populate the buffer and this is what is happening asynchronously?

Comment: Prior to calling `tmp = ...`, what is the value of `[[[InternalContactsHandler sharedBuffer] contacts] count]`?

Comment: @DonMag 0 when calling it in my own code, but 49 when calling it in old code where it is also used. Really confused.

Comment: I did some research in debug. Se edited post above. :)

Comment: You have to look at the code that is populating the original array. When is that happening? Is it calling out to a server and parsing returned data? If so, are you waiting for that to complete before trying to access the result?

Comment: @WhipperSnapper Add more code.